# ANOVA (linear model option in R) in gui and with handtyped syntax

Tags: user-interface, anova

I am running an analysis of variance two ways. I get two very different outputs. Can anyone explain why?

The first line wpgroup is where to focus. There are markedly different Sum of Squares etc.

Here is the handtype:

anova(lm(STAI2~wpgroup + STAI1 +STAI1*wpgroup, data=zCLINICALwp))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: STAI2
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq  F value    Pr(>F)
wpgroup         3  1082.7   360.9   7.0507 0.0001269 ***
STAI1           1 14644.7 14644.7 286.1007 < 2.2e-16 ***
wpgroup:STAI1   3    24.3     8.1   0.1581 0.9244007
Residuals     379 19399.9    51.2

Here is the gui:

> .gui.working.env$model.lm <- lm(formula=STAI2 ~ wpgroup + STAI1 + STAI1*wpgroup,data=.gui.working.env$zCLINICALwp,na.action=na.omit)
>
> Anova(.gui.working.env$model.lm,type='II')

Anova Table (Type II tests)

Response: STAI2
               Sum Sq  Df  F value Pr(>F)
wpgroup          22.8   3   0.1487 0.9305
STAI1         14644.7   1 286.1007 <2e-16 ***
wpgroup:STAI1    24.3   3   0.1581 0.9244

### Residuals     19399.9 379

Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '***' 0.01 '' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

> summary(.gui.working.env$model.lm)

Any ideas?

Thank you,
Aurelie